# Can 1000Base-T Ethernet be connected to 100Base-T Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, lan

I want to connect 1000Base-T Ethernet to 100Base-TX Ethernet. 1000Base-T MDI lines have 8 signals whereas 100Base-TX has 4 signals. Does this create any problem if I connect both of them or auto-negotiation works such a way that only 4 signals will be used from 1000Base-T?
Thanks

Comment: use a router...

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Seriously, you don't need a router for that. Maybe you don't mean a router?

Comment: @Justme, Fair point. Router seems to imply NAT these days, but it didn't used to. A switch then. Not to advertise, but something premade like https://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8212505&SRCCODE=3WGOOGLEBASE&cm_mmc_o=VRqCjC7BBTkwCjCECjCE will probably end up cheaper than designing and building one's own 2 port interface.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy No, a router does not imply NAT, a router actually routes IP packets over a network while a switch just switches Ethernet packets between LAN devices. And you don't need a switch either, gigabit devices can talk directly with 100M devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All consumer hardware you encounter that can do 1000Base-T (Gigabit Ethernet) can also do Fast Ethernet (100Base-TX) and will downgrade as necessary. Auto-Negotiation just works.

Doesn't apply to all hardware, though. I know of a class of sampling devices whose ethernet frames *need* Gigabit Ethernet, so they simply don't work with 100Base.